# Computer doesn't boot up owing to disk errors

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a HP laptop and it's currently not booting up and says that it is checking for disk errors. I want to use the recovery disc provided with the laptop. But when I insert the recovery disc, I get the following dialog box:

It says that it will erase all data from **OS disk**. What does it mean? Is it the C:/ drive or the whole hard drive?

[image]

Comment: Those old Restore CDs just wipe the whole machine so it's like you just bought it. Wait to see if someone comes up with a better suggestion in an answer, otherwise you will lose all your data.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean?  "It says that it will erase all data from OS disk."

The recovery disc provided by the Manufacturer will return the machine to its state when it was new.

So:

(a) All data and applications will be erased (deleted)

(b) The Windows installed will be a prior version and will need to be updated.

(c) All factory partitions will be restore to original.

The operation deletes and formats the whole disk. I assume you just have one disk.

I have done this same thing on Lenovo computers and it works fine assuming you wish to do a full recovery.

You may wish to remove the hard disk first, put in a carrier and see if you can recover data (disk appears to be damaged). You can also boot with a bootable USB Key to try to recover data.

Comment: If I reinstall windows .iso using a bootable usb, will it still delete all the partitions or just the C:/ drive?

Comment: If you have one drive, the Recovery USB will initialize the entire disk.  At least this has been true when I have used them. If you have a dual boot system, you need to plan that all will be deleted.  That is, have backups.

Comment: @John Whoa, you only answered one question on this day.... say what! Is your name really HarryMC?

Comment: /me chuckles. :)